# Zend/Db not working in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework3

How to connect mysql database using ZF3 db factory method.

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
      'host'      => MASTER_HOST,
      'username'  => MASTER_USER,
      'password'  => MASTER_PASSWORD,
      'dbname'    => DB_ADMIN,
      'port'      => MASTER_HOST_PORT,
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

In ZF3 (or ZF2), you must use  `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`

```
$config = array(
  'driver'   => 'Pdo',
  'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
);
// or
$config = $serviceLocator->get('Config')['db'];

$db = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config);
```

Documentation:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/tutorial.dbadapter.html